# mapreduce with polymodel

Tags: google-app-engine, mapreduce

We are thinking use mapreduce over a polymodel kind but is not possible filter only for subclass. what is the reason?

we are using model.get_by_key etc etc propertly.

We can filter over mapper after fetch entity but we neeed iterarte over a lot entites for anything spending time and money.

any idea? how built my own DataInputEntityReader?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this is not yet possible. Mapreduce framework doesn't support queries with filters yet. You'll have to implement your reader. I gave some directions on the mailing list for this: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/app-engine-pipeline-api/hE17YiNnuMM